# Remove Console.WriteLine from a Blazor WebAssemble app for production

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Having `Console.WriteLine` to assist building a blazor webassembly app is helpful, but is there a way to remove them for production?  I've tried to run app with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Production or run my app in Release mode, it does not remove the Console.WriteLine by default.

Comment: You could create a custom logger class that will only log things when it's on debug... but I'm not sure if that is what you want

Comment: I was thinking about that too but would like to see if there is a better way first, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to use a ILogger and configure the log level your appsettings.json:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-configuration

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: After playing around it more, I realized using ILogger gives me what I wanted, though not without struggle. Thanks.